# How to align highcharts legend to bottom right?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to align a legend at the bottom right in highstock. It used to work until I was forced to upgrade to highstock 1.3.4.

The problem is that now the navigator is covering the legend. This is not ideal:

http://jsfiddle.net/sy8dE/

I'm aligning the legend as follows:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        floating: true,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        align: 'right'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
});
```

How can I get the navigator to NOT cover the legend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to specifying the alignment of the legend, you can also offset it using x and y offsets. For instance, in your case you could move it down a bit like this:

```
 legend: {
        enabled: true,
        floating: true,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        align:'right',
        y:40
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqvNJ/

The other legend options are specified here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.y

Comment: That will do. Thanks :)

Comment: have in mind that you have to specify `chart : { spacingBottom : n}` or `chart : { spacingTop : n}` where `n` is a number grater than what you specify in option `y` in `legend:{}` otherwise you won't see your legend.